# unable to write to file in binary mode when the call to write is made through switch-case ladder

Tags: c++11, switch-statement, binary-data

I'm trying create a .dat file where i'm trying to store object data by writing the data in binary mode. This works perfectly fine when i do this in the main() or in a loop, but things get weird when i try to do this task in a switch case. When i put the binary mode writing code in switch case, it doesn't write anything to the file!

```
class PlacementPortal
{
    private:
        int prn;
        char name[20];
        int marks;
    public:
        PlacementPortal():prn(0),name(""),marks(0){}
        void accept(){  .....   }       
        void display(){ ....    }
};
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("place.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);

    int c;
    PlacementPortal p;
    while(1)
    {
            cout<<"Enter 1 for add data, 2, for exit"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        cin.get();
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:     
                p.accept();
                    p.display();
                        fout.write((char*)&p,sizeof(PlacementPortal));
                    break;
            case 2:
                        exit(0);
                            break;
        }   }   
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be written to the "place.dat" but only the file is created and it remains empty
P.S. i've included fstream and iostream and also made sure that i'm not using datatype string.

Comment: I suspect that the code you have in `PlacementPortal::accept()` is the source of your problem. It's hard to tell for certain where the problem is without a [mcve].

Comment: ofstream.close() is often the problem in such cases.

  [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/

Comment: ofstream.close() is the solution! Apparently ofstream has to be closed in order for the changed to be reflected in ifstream!